# Pi run command and wait

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wait

I'm new to this so please bear with me.
I'm trying to write a piece of code to run a command, when relay closes a circuit and another when it opens.
I've altered a sample piece of code I've found and it seems to do most of what I want.
I've set it up to run mp3's while I'm test/learning.
but my problem is that I only want it to play the corresponding mp3 once, but it keeps playing the mp3 over an over again.

I thought about using time time.sleep() and using a large number so theres a long pause.
but the circuit may close in that time and it won't play the mp3 in that time.

here's my code

```
import os
import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)

print("------------------")
print("   trigger test   ")
print("------------------")

print GPIO.input(22)

while True:
   if ( GPIO.input(22) == False ):
      print("Triggered")
      os.system('omxplayer -o hdmi cow.mp3')
   else:
      print ("Waiting to be triggered again")
      os.system('omxplayer -o hdmi sample.mp3')
```

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button. Also, whatever you did that added an extra blank line between every two lines, don't do that. (I fixed both for you this time.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Is it that you want to play the MP3 only when the state changes from True to False, but instead you're playing it over and over as long as the state is False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, what you want is to play the MP3 every time the state changes from True to False, but instead your code is playing it over and over as long as the state stays False.

As a side note, `if ( GPIO.input(22) == False ):` violates about half a dozen rules of Pythonic style, so I'm going to fix that rather than try to write everything else in your style.

---

One way to solve this is to add another loop that spins until the state is True, and only then go back to the outer loop

```
while True:
   if not GPIO.input(22):
      print("Triggered")
      os.system('omxplayer -o hdmi cow.mp3')
      while not GPIO.input(22):
          time.sleep(.1)
   else:
      print ("Waiting to be triggered again")
      os.system('omxplayer -o hdmi sample.mp3')
      while GPIO.input(22):
          time.sleep(.1)
```

---

However, a better solution is to use the edge detection that's built into the `GPIO` library, as described in the [Interrupts and Edge detection](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) section of the docs:

> An edge is the change in state of an electrical signal from LOW to HIGH (rising edge) or from HIGH to LOW (falling edge). Quite often, we are more concerned by a change in state of an input than it's value. This change in state is an event.
>
> To avoid missing a button press while your program is busy doing something else, there are two ways to get round this:
>
> - the `wait_for_edge()` function
> - the `event_detected()` function
> - a threaded callback function that is run when an edge is detected

(Yes, that's three ways, not two…)

So, you could do this:

```
while True:
   if not GPIO.input(22):
      print("Triggered")
      os.system('omxplayer -o hdmi cow.mp3')
      GPIO.wait_for_edge(22, GPIO.RISING)
   else:
      print ("Waiting to be triggered again")
      os.system('omxplayer -o hdmi sample.mp3')
      GPIO.wait_for_edge(22, GPIO.FALLING)
```

Comment: There _might_ be a race condition in your `wait_for_edge()` solution - if the GPIO goes high then low quickly two moos might be heard.

Comment: @mhawke: Well, if it goes high anywhere during the playing of the first moo, then goes low again after, then it will play again, which I think is the desired behavior. So, the fact that if it goes high a fraction of a millisecond after the first moo finishes it will do the same thing as if it went high during the moo doesn't seem like a problem.

Comment: @mhawke: Unless you're talking about signal bounce—sometimes toggling high will be read as toggling high then low then high again. Normally you take care of that with a capacitor, but the docs show how you can deal with it purely in software if you want.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks the first code worked perfectly. I'll learn a bit more about edge functions if you think they're a better solution